# Wordpress is page str replace

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, str-replace

I have page on wordpress site

http://upsourcemobileservices.com/solutions/

in footer.php I have added the following:

```
if(is_page('solutions')){
    echo str_replace("The MVNi","The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators.","The MVNi");
}
```

but it is not changing the contents of the page.

To my knowledge, Syntax is correct `str_replace(find,replace,string)`

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried using jQuery

```
function replaceText(jQuery) {
    $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:nth-child(1)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbnail-content'>The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators.</div>");
    $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:nth-child(2)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbnail-content'>Primarily aimed at existing Telcos our MVNc solution integrates your existing platforms with ours through the use of APIs.</div>");
    $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:nth-child(3)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbnail-content'>UMS turnkey solution is a complete MVNO in a box.</div>");
    $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:nth-child(4)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbnail-content'>This solution allows you to select the products and services that you want and integrate them with your existing platforms.</div>");
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
```

but can't seem to get that working either, here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vzy9R/3/

Comment: You're not using `str_replace` correctly. The third parameter should be the "haystack" in which you want to find the "needle" (the first parameter).

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. I want to replace entire string, not just one word.

Comment: Is your goal to display a different footer on a specific WordPress page?

Comment: If you look at that Solutions page, you'll see 4 thumbnails or "excerpts" of its child pages (MVNi, MVNc, MVNO Turnkey, and MVNO Customized). The theme allows me to fetch excerpt (in # of characters) for all child pages, but not set # of characters for each, so if I set excerpt character # to 8 it will fetch first 8 characters of each child page, or if I set to 100 the first 100, etc. I want each excerpt to end at a sentence, which is why I'm trying to replace "The MVNi" with the full sentence in the code. Once I can get one working, I want to do same for all 4 thumbnails.

Comment: In this case you would want for your third parameter in `str_replace`  (haystack) to be the PHP variable that stores the excerpt.

Comment: I believe it is. Since I want to replace entire excerpt (currently have set to 8 characters which is why its simply "The MVNi") I have set both `find` and `string` to the same value, because I want to change entire value.

Comment: I mean that you have to set it as the actual PHP variable, not that value of that variable. For example, if the excerpt is stored as a variable named `$the_excerpt`, then you would do this: `str_replace("The MVNi","The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators.",$the_excerpt);`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your previous statement. I don't believe the string that I want to replace is being stored anywhere as a variable. The theme's functionality simply fetches the first X amount of characters of each child page. Keep in mind I'll be preforming this customization on several pages so if the excerpts have to be stored as an actual PHP variable, they'll need to less annonymous than `$the_excerpt`. On the page in question alone there's 4 excerpts, so that means 4 find and replace codes.

Comment: Could you post the code from the theme as an edit to your original post, so I can take a look?

Comment: It's `str_replace(replace_this, with_this, in_this_string)`.

Comment: The fetching of excerpts is done in the front-end by the theme's GUI. Here's a screenshot: http://snag.gy/xFO5L.jpg

Comment: @RCV - That's the syntax I'm following. I want to replace the entire string, not part of it. Hence why `replace_this` and `in_this_string` are identical in my code.

Comment: Then it should work, what's the problem now ?

Comment: @RCV - Take a look at the link in my original post, "The MVNi" is not being replaced with "The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators." The original string is intact.

Comment: @LordTubington, Do you want to replace `The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators.` with `The MVNi` ?

Comment: @RCV - no, the opposite. I want to replace `The MVNi` with `The MVNi solution was created to ensure that wireless communications are available to the smaller Telco operators.`

Comment: @LordTubington, Then your code should work, what's wrong ?

Comment: I don't know, hence why I'm here ;) Placing anywhere in footer.php does nothing. Placing in header.php just above `</head>` tag echos the text across the top of the site as if I wrote the code to simply `echo` without `str_replace`, instead of finding the string in question and replacing it with what I want it to.

Comment: To clarify, because the theme's GUI won't let me specify excerpt length per child page (i.e. for MVNi = fetch the first 114 characters, for MVNc = fetch the first 122 characters, for MVNO Turnkey = fetch the first 49 characters, for MVNO Customized = fetch the first 123 characters .) I'm trying to find a work around, and I figured `str_replace` would be simplest. Here's a mockup of the end result I'm striving for: http://snag.gy/sO3bK.jpg

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but just an FYI, I also tried doing this in jQuery, but for some reason this jsFiddle is not working http://jsfiddle.net/vzy9R/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery `eq()` selector to find elements containing class **portfolio-thumbnail-content** and then using `.replaceWith()` I was able to load my teaser content (excerpts) ending with complete sentences.

For example, the About page:

```
(function ($) {
 $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:eq(0)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbail-content'>This is my new complete sentence teaser for Team.</div>");
 $(".portfolio-thumbnail-content:eq(1)").replaceWith("<div class='portfolio-thumbail-content'>This is my new complete sentence teaser for Partners.</div>");
})(jQuery);
```

Then I had to figure out a way to implement those scripts into the body of those pages, so I wrote my own shortcodes and added them to functions.php

```
//[replaceTextAbout]
 function replaceTextAbout_func( $atts ){
  return "<script src='/javascript/custom/replaceText-About.js'></script>";
 }
 add_shortcode( 'replaceTextAbout', 'replaceTextAbout_func' );
```